# Invalid filter when using MapServer as a WFS

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, mapserver, html

I'm trying to use Openlayers and Mapserver to display a shapefile. My HTML file is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');    
    var googleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google', {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE});

    // Create WFS layer
    var wfsLayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
           strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
           protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
               url: "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi/wfs?&map=wfs_1.map&",
               featureType: "MLSOA",
               featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver",
               srsName: "EPSG:27700",
               version: "1.1.0", 
               PropertyName: "NAME" //also tried "FID"
           })
       });

    //add layers
    map.addLayers([googleLayer,wfsLayer]);

    // Set initial center location
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.13, 51.55).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()),5);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This loads a google-map base map, and should overlay a shapefile over all of England. When the page loads the coordinates of the bounding box of the map are sent to MapServer. I can see that it is sending just the lon/lat values. In my mapfile, I have the projection of the data defined as follows, in both the intro part, and also in the layer:

```
 PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:27700"
 END
```

However, the response from the server gives me an error `WFS server error. Invalid or Unsupported FILTER in 
GetFeature`, and I don't know whether it is due to an incorrect bounding box, or whether I have a mistake with my query using `PropertyName`. From searching online [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/ticket/3955) appears to have been a bug, but I don't know whether it is still a problem or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" version="1.1.0" language="en-US" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="filter">
    <ows:ExceptionText>msWFSGetFeature(): WFS server error. Invalid or Unsupported FILTER in 
GetFeature : &lt;
    Filter ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"&gt;
  &lt;BBOX&gt;
    &lt;Envelope gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326"&gt;
      &lt;lowerCorner&gt;-55.50109375 43.134977942511&lt;/lowerCorner&gt;
      &lt;upperCorner&gt;55.24109375 59.593781185019&lt;/upperCorner&gt;
    &lt;/Envelope&gt;
  &lt;/BBOX&gt;
&lt;/Filter&gt;
</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

What do I need to do to fix this? Should I make sure that I am passing a bounding box in `epsg:27700` coordinates? Or can Mapserver accept lon/lat and project them into the required coordinate system?

---

I have asked another [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16006/querying-mapserver-using-wfs-functionality) on the same topic recently, but I had a different problem then!

Comment: Try to change the strategy to fixed or filter and see if you get any different results.

Comment: Would it just be `strategies: 'fixed'` ?

Comment: it would be new `strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],`

Answer (score 1):

Those **&** in the url look suspicious, try without:

```
 url: "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi/wfs?&map=wfs_1.map&",
                                         ^             ^
```

if it still does not work try to remove only the first one (the *one* before map=..)

Comment: The `&` at the end is required by the specification (see table 34 WS Common ~ https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=20040 for KVP syntax). The `&` after the `?` is incorrect as you say